# iOS 6 MPMoviePlayerViewController Crash

Tags: ios, video

I am having an odd crash when trying to upgrade my application to iOS 6.  Note: this crash is only occurring on iPhone, iPad is ok.

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x933f7d0
<Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x933f7d0
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x933f7d0
<Error>: CGContextDrawShading: invalid context 0x933f7d0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x933f7d0
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x933f7d0
-[Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x933f7d0
```

This occurs when the MPMoviePlayerViewController is initialized:

```
    self.moviePlayerController = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:_videoUrl] autorelease];
```

Where moviePlayerController is a synthesized and retained property.

Here is the full setup:

```
-(void)setupMediaPlayer {
//NSLog(@"VideoViewController:setupMediaPlayer");

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;    

if (self.moviePlayerController == nil) {
    self.moviePlayerController = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:_videoUrl] autorelease];
}
else {
    [self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer setContentURL:_videoUrl];
}

[[self.moviePlayerController view] setFrame:viewFrame];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:[self.moviePlayerController view]];

}
```

I've checked _videoURL and it is giving a good URL every time.

I attempted to change this to a MPMoviePlayerController instead, but then none of my notifications are firing except the generalCallback.  Setup like this (but would have .moviePlayer removed in the non-ViewController option):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer];
```

I'm stumped as this is working perfectly in iOS 5.

Notes:  I am using Three20 for this project and TTNavigator.  TTNavigator seems to not be supporting the new supportedOrientations setup so on iPad I had to build my tabbar from scratch so that I would not get the following error and so it would launch in Landscape:

Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

I am still getting this error on iPhone but I do not know if it could be related to the video player crash which is not occurring on iPad.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I was having the same problem, but it seems that everything seems to be working even after the errors are dumped.

If you are not getting to see the video, it seems that now the video only starts loading when the moviePlayer is actually displayed (presented). If you are waiting for the loadState to change before presenting, you'll be waiting forever (I guess).

Comment: This was actually crashing the app after errors are thrown.  I ended up having to ditch MPMoviePlayerViewController for a custom MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: Are you sure the app crashes right after the errors are thrown? Those errors seem to be thrown right after the MPMoviePlayerViewController calls initWithContentURL, but the code that comes next is still called.

Comment: -[Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x933f7d0 << This message is not thrown in my app. This might be your problem.

Comment: I think that this most likely has something to do with three20 not mingling correctly and UIWindow control that is acting oddly when using the MPMoviePlayerViewController vs. the MPMoviePlayerController which has no issues.

Comment: You can try to pinpoint when the last message is thrown. Just add some breakpoints to the code and hit continue until you get the last message. You'll know the problem is happening after the last breakpoint you passed.

Comment: I've already done that and the breakpoint is on setContentUrl

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I don't really understand what is happening. However it seems that we are the only ones that have this problem. What are we doing wrong?